# How to find A and k constants of the equation y_n = A cos(x_n + k) using Numerical method

Tags: optimization, numerical-methods, nonlinear-optimization, parameter-estimation, artificial-intelligence

How to find A and k 
 constants of the equation $y_n = A cos(x_n + k)$ when $y_1 ... y_n$ and $x_1 ... x_n$ is available in a iterative process. Data is received iteratively. All data is not available at once.

In other terms, I want to fit the data to a cosine where I have some data for a segment of the curve but don't have data at 0 degrees or 90 degrees so cannot using zero crossing.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use linear approximation to fit
$$
y_n=a\cos(x_n)-b\sin(x_n)
$$
Then $(A,k)$ are the polar coordinates of the point $(a,b)$.

Use an incremental scheme for linear regression.

Answer (score 0):

It is just a **fit** topic. If you use python, a small pieces of code can solve this. https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html

Comment: That function uses Levenberg-Marquardt. I think it requires all the data at once. Sorry I wasn't clear in my question. I don't have all data at once. I need a iterative method.

Comment: Generally, before fit you'd best to interpolate data.

Comment: I don't have all data at once so I don't have data to interpolate. So I need method that would give me a estimate based on the current input and, update in next iteration.

Comment: What do you want to know exactly?  Can you give a small instrustration?

Comment: I have a unknown sinusoidal signal. I want to find A and k of the equation  y_n = A cos(x_n + k). A is the unknown amplitude of the signal and k is the unknown phase shift. But i may have only two sets of data that are very close to each other at a time. e.g.  x = 33.33 y = 3.1, x = 33.34 y = 3.2. This is because I'm running this program on a microchip, I cannot keep a lot of data. But I could keep $x_i ,y_i, x_{i-1},y_{i-1}$ at a time.

Comment: What's the period of the sinusoidal signal? If you know it you can capture 2 or more data of x and y in a period. If you don't know, can you capture data as quickly as possible? As the time goes, the data captured should be sinusoidal.

Comment: I don't know the period of the signal. But I can capture data fast. As the time goes data captured is sinusoidal. If I can find correct A and k, then this equation will be correct for any y_n and x_n.

Comment: So, you capture data as fast as possible and plot x VS. y and observe what will happen. In principle, it is a sinusoidal signal.

Comment: @user8462 : Your formula implies a period of $2\pi$, this one would call an a-priori known frequency.

Comment: I would set x to some arbitrary value in the plant, then the output y is A cos(x + k). But the values I input as x does not cause a full cycle. In this case no period.